# How to calculate percentage for each group depends on the different variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This the dummy dataset R code:

```
c <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40, 2, 40, 10, 50)
b <- c(40, 2, 40, 10, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
a <- c(10, 50, 3, 60, 100,40, 2, 40, 10, 50)
id <- c("a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "b", "a", "c")
variation <- c("a3", "a3", "b1", "a2", "b1","a3", "a1", "b1", "a1", "b1" )

data <- data.frame(id, a, b, c, variation)
head(data)
#    id   a  b  c variation
# 1   a  10 40 10        a3
# 2   b  50  2 20        a3
# 3   b   3 40 30        b1
# 4   a  60 10 40        a2
# 5   c 100 50 50        b1
# 6   a  40 10 40        a3
# 7   b   2 20  2        a1
# 8   b  40 30 40        b1
# 9   a  10 40 10        a1
# 10  c  50 50 50        b1
```

I can calculate percentages for individual id after filtering:

```
data_filter <- data %>% filter(id == "a")
data_filter
#   id  a  b  c variation
# 1  a 10 40 10        a3
# 2  a 60 10 40        a2
# 3  a 40 10 40        a3
# 4  a 10 40 10        a1

# Data transformation
data_filter_percentage <- data_filter %>% 
  group_by(variation) %>% # Variable to be transformed
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(perc = `n` / sum(`n`)) %>% 
  arrange(perc) %>%
  mutate(labels = scales::percent(perc))

head(data_filter_percentage)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#   variation     n  perc labels
#   <chr>     <int> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 a1            1  0.25 25%   
# 2 a2            1  0.25 25%   
# 3 a3            2  0.5  50%
```

However, my question is,  Is it possible to perform above pipeline for all "id" without filtering individually?

Comment: There’s no need to put regular variables (such as `n`) in backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following workflow:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  count(variation) %>%
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n), labels = scales::percent(perc)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Briefly,

```r
data %>%
  count(id, variation) %>%
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n), labels = scales::percent(perc), .by = id)

# # A tibble: 7 × 5
#   id    variation     n  perc labels
#   <chr> <chr>     <int> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 a     a1            1  0.25 25%   
# 2 a     a2            1  0.25 25%   
# 3 a     a3            2  0.5  50%   
# 4 b     a1            1  0.25 25%   
# 5 b     a3            1  0.25 25%   
# 6 b     b1            2  0.5  50%   
# 7 c     b1            2  1    100%
```